# What is the point of the "E-" numbers, and how to avoid them in general?

Tags: php, numbers, ieee-754

I can't tell you how many times my functions have broken because they expect an actual number, such as `0.0000312345669999999971003061538521450302141602151095867156982422`, but what I get is something like this: `3.1234567E-5`.

Is there some way to tell PHP to always auto-convert these to actual numbers? I don't understand who would ever want something with `E-` in it, messing up all kinds of checks and filters and assumptions when you are supposed to feed it a number and PHP (and others) for some reason considers this to be a valid number.

What is the deal with these "special" numbers? Why does it exist and why would anyone need, want or prefer it?

I already do have a way to convert them, so I'm not asking how to manually convert them.

Comment: It's called exponential or scientific notation. Anything that parses numbers in PHP should understand it.

Comment: `E` stands for `times 10 raised to`

Comment: It's used to avoid lots of zeroes, e.g. `1e-10` instead of `0.0000000001` and `1e10` instead of `10000000000`

Answer (score 0):

> What is the deal with these "special" numbers?

Scientific notation, which represents numbers in a form like 3.72•10<sup>17</sup>, is a long-standing practice, with origins going back centuries, and antecedents before that. Since early computer equipment did not have modern typography and was only capable of printing simple strings of characters, “E”, standing for exponent, was used to denote the “times ten to the power of” part of scientific notation.

> Why does it exist and why would anyone need, want or prefer it?

People who work with very big or very small numbers prefer exponential notation because it requires many fewer characters than writing out numbers with plain decimal notation and quickly conveys information about how big or how small the number is.

> Is there some way to tell PHP to always auto-convert these to actual numbers?

I am unfamiliar with PHP but, based on the lack of other responses so far, I will hazard a guess as to no, there is no way to change PHP’s default, but you can write code that selects the format it is using, as with `printf` and `%f`.

> don't understand who would ever want something with E- in it, messing up all kinds of checks and filters and assumptions when you are supposed to feed it a number and PHP (and others) for some reason considers this to be a valid number.

Exponential notation is a valid way of representing numbers, just as decimal without exponential notation is. Neither is found in nature; both were invented by humans, and neither has a claim to be more valid than the other.

A great variety of software uses exponential notation for input and output. Generally, if you are encountering exponential notation, you will be better of designing software to accept it rather than trying to avoid it.